# Calling method from another class and correctness of the code

Tags: java, android

Hi I am new in android and I am writting alarm clock. I have got small problem, how to call method from other class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, OnCheckedChangeListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View w) {
            Alarm_Reciver alarm = new Alarm_Reciver();
            alarm.set...?
```

Next class

```
public class Alarm_Reciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

AlarmManager alarm_manager;
private PendingIntent pending_intent;
MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


}


public void setAlarm(Context context, Intent intent) {



   mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.d_s_h);
   mp.start();
   PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
   PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
   wl.acquire();
   Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   wl.release();
   ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, Alarm_Reciver.class);
   PackageManager pac = context.getPackageManager();
   pac.setComponentEnabledSetting(cn,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
   if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
       alarm_manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
       Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm_Reciver.class);
       pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
       alarm_manager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60 * 1000, pending_intent);
       Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }


}

public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm_Reciver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarManager.cancel(sender);
    if (alarm_manager != null) {
        alarm_manager.cancel(pending_intent);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, Alarm_Reciver.class);
    PackageManager pac = context.getPackageManager();
    pac.setComponentEnabledSetting(cn,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

}

1.
So, I want to call method setAlarm when the button2 is clicked, I tried several times (with context and intent for example `alarm.setAlarm(context, intent)` or `alarm.setAlarm(this, context)` , it didn`t work, also I want to call method cancel alarm in button off, but as I understand it is the same as with button on.

2.
My next question is, it is write properly, should the alarm code occur in instructions if() or it should be only in method setAlarm() outside if()? Maybe some part of code should be in onReceive() method. I will add some things later, but now it is ok right?

**@UPGRADE**

```
Ad1.
```

I tried to add setAlarm in XML but it throws me:

`Corresponding method handler 'public void SetAlarm(android.view.View)' not found`

so I tried to add in my XML(tool:ignore): OnClick like this:

`tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,OnClick"`

instead of

`tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"`

When I have got my XML like

`tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,OnClick`

It throws: Method 'SetAlarm' is missing in 'MainActivity' or has incorrect signature

I have read about this on stackoverflow in another thread and somebody write this:
    Are you using the correct signature for the method?

```
Methods defines using the onClick attribute must meet the following requirements:

must be public
must have a void return value
must have a View object as parameter (which is the view that was clicked)
like

public void addWord(View view) {
//your action
}
```

My method doesn`t have View object so I must add it? How to do this?

Ad2.
  It should be: (if statement at the end)

```
alarm_manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm_Reciver.class);
pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
alarm_manager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60 * 1000, pending_intent);
Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
});
```

Or:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
alarm_manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm_Reciver.class);
pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
alarm_manager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60 * 1000, pending_intent);
Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I mean in if() statement should be all code or outside if() statement?

Thanks for help, I hope that I described it clear.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking, especially in question 2.

Answer (score 0):

for the first question
you can solve it by adding 
android:onClick:setAlarm in the XML code for the button

i do not really understand the second question

Comment: I upgraded my question, beacuse it was too many characters to send it as a comment